# IntelliJ debug not function normally

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, step-through

I have code that I am trying to debug with IntelliJ (2016.2.5). The debugger used to run just fine, but recently the console started displaying:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:53186', transport: 'socket'
```

(the port number seems irrelevant since it changes at compile time)

My problem is that I cannot step through the code -"step through" is disabled- when running in debug mode. As far as I can remember I haven't changed any settings, so I am battling to pinpoint the reason for this problem

Thanx

Comment: Found the answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem (I am quite new to IntelliJ): I had an infinite loop in my code.
:P